# How can this jQuery script be written better?

Tags: jquery, variables, href

Below is the working script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.lang = new jquery_lang_js();
$(document).ready(function() {  
    window.lang.run();
 $(".jp").click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();      
    var $this = $(this);        
    var id = $this.attr('href');
    window.lang.change('jp');
});

 $(".en").click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();      
    var $this = $(this);        
    var id = $this.attr('href');
    window.lang.change('en');
});
});

</script>

<a href="#" class="en">Switch to English</a>
<a href="#" class="jp">Switch to Japanese</a>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////

Now, before quickly telling me "what's wrong with that if it's working?" I have few more classes to add so I am trying to get rid of redundancy.  I know how to combine a href with same function but here, each class has variable function and I can't figure this out on my own.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.lang = new jquery_lang_js();
$(document).ready(function() {  
    window.lang.run();
  $this.each(function(){ 
 $("a").click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();      
  // var $this = $(this);       
    var id = $this.attr('href');
    window.lang.change('jp');
    window.lang.change('en');
});
});
});

</script>
```

And this is not working.

And isn't it bit harsh to comment that I should learn the basics of jQuery first before asking question here just because I can't replace  var $this = $(this); to  $this.each(function(){ properly?

I am new to jQuery and I am trying to learn by asking a question here. Saying I should learn the basics first isn't very constructive.  If you are not helping that fine but what's all this criticism for?

Comment: This is probably a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com then.

Comment: If substituting `$(this)` for `$this` poses a problem, I suggest you take a step back and start to learn the very basics of JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: and he can learn right now! why sending him away..? `var $this=$(this)` makes just things better if you need it in that scope more than once. so you are right, in your code you don't need it looks like.

Comment: this is the best jQuery resource out there btw, have fun ^^ https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/

Answer (score 5):

I like using data attributes for this kind of a scenario...

```
var lang = new jquery_lang_js();
$(function() {  
    lang.run();

    $(".lang").click(function (e) {
        var ln = $( this ).data( "lang" );

        if ( ln ) { 
            lang.change( ln );
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});


<a href="#" class="lang" data-lang="en">Switch to English</a>
<a href="#" class="lang" data-lang="jp">Switch to Japanese</a>
```

Also, about `this`, inside of a callback on an event listener like this, it will refer to the actual DOM element that was clicked. You can take that DOM element and wrap it with `$( this )` and it basically gives you a jQuery object containing the clicked element.

Comment: Should use .attr('data-whatever') for better compatibility

Comment: @Huangism I believe that `.data` is compatible with most browsers, even the old one's.

Comment: Thanks.  This works & I see what you are doing here. (well, let me qualify by saying I think I understand what you are doing.)  I learn by looking at example and this is very helpful.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Sweet, no problem man. I wrote an article about `this` the other day if you want some more knowledge... http://tech.pro/tutorial/1192/avoiding-the-this-problem-in-javascript

Comment: I've just bookmarked your article & I plan to share your article with others who are learning jQuery.  Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @Huangism no, data('whatever') is perfectly fine

Comment: @DavidFregoli casting bug in some versions of jquery

Answer (score 3):

I want to clarify something about the use of `$this = $(this);` in general, and your use of it.

Using `$(this)` is the same thing as taking `this` and wrapping it into a jQuery object, using `$()`. Essentially, if `this` is the same thing as an element `span.test`, then `$(this)` is equivalent to taking the `$("span#test")` at the "index" that you are looking at (I use the word "index" loosely).

Now, what does this mean in terms of performance? It means that every time you use `$(this)` you are taking `this` and creating an object out of it. Doing so generally costs significantly more overhead than would initially finding `$(this)` and setting it to a variable, such as `$this`. *However*, (here it comes!) in your situation, you are only using `$(this)` once, each time you declare it. Since the program has to make `$(this)` once anyway (since it has to find it to set it to a variable, or for immediate use), it would be better, *in your situation*, to not use `$this` and to instead skip the creation and use of the variable (which would actually make your situation more expensive) and to, instead, just use `$(this)`, directly.

Normally, however, you would be right to use `$this`. For sake of sanity, when I code, I always use `$this`, initially, and remove it when I am done, if necessary.

Comment: You are wrong, `this` is a `dom element`, `$(this)` is wrapping that dom element with a jQuery object, there's no finding involved.

Comment: @DavidFregoli - you are right - it is not *finding*, but it is still *creating*, so the result was the same but the explanation was a bit off. I have updated my explanation accordingly.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for explaining this in detail.

Comment: No problem - it is one of those things that developers should always learn when they learn jQuery. There are a lot of good sources out there, but none of the beginner tutorials cover it in detail, and developers typically don't look into increasing performance until they start to advance past novice topics. It's great that you learned it this way! :)

Comment: I'd like to point out that `$this` is not a keyword in any way (even the `$` part), it's just a convention. You could give it any other variable name. It's also a convention to start variable  names that point to jQuery object with the dollar sign.

Comment: @DavidFregoli - I know - which is why I chose to refer to it as "a variable, such as `$this`" (second paragraph). I continued to use `$this` as that is both a convention and what was used in the OP.

Comment: I know you know, I was just clarifying for him :p

Comment: Fair enough. :) For a second there I thought I forgot to put that into my answer haha